# Why is JavaFX still not working in my IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

So i read that FX is no longer included in jdk since java11, so i followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682195/how-to-get-javafx-and-java-11-working-in-intellij-idea) to install javafx. I also added the mentioned VM option. Somehow, it still says that there is a module missing but I don't understand?

At least it already recognizes fx classes but why not the module "com.example.fxgui" when it is right there?

[image]

This is my "Run -> Edit Configuration" window:

[image]

Comment: it's not finding _your_ module which often is a related to stale project state. BTW: no screenshots of text (like the error message), please

Comment: And how do I fix it?

Comment: Follow one of the steps [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: Please create an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach the sample project zipped to reproduce the case. Thank you