# Java 11 / IntelliJ: Module not found

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-9, java-11

I'm exploring the modularity of Java 9+ and I'm stuck with adding JavaFX. I'm using IntelliJ and OpenJDK11 but IntelliJ can't seem to find JavaFX even though I have added the library and added the deps in the module-info.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK OpenJDK does not have JavaFX, it is a separate project OpenJFX.

Comment: I know that's why I added JavaFX seperately.

Comment: was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11/52470141#52470141) not helpful as well?

Comment: isn't that the "old way" of doing it? I want to make use of jlink and the new modular system. I think this requires a module-info.java if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This is issue of Intellij's version so check out this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/1901571

Comment: I would configure Gradle to use javafx dependencies from the Maven Central: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the library > Add to Modules... > Choose the module which requires it

[image: libraries settings]

Comment: That is not the Gradle way to go. With Gradle, if you refresh the project, it will overwrite the manual project settings.