# JavaFX packaging: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I package a JavaFX application using maven and OpenJDK 1.8
The relevant part from my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>ui.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now importantly **this used to work**. I know this because I specifically made a git commit where the packaging finally worked.
After a day or so and multiple builds like this (I can't figure out what changed), I can no longer launch the jar because of the following error:

```
$ java -jar target/app.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class ui.Main Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

When I view the contents of the Jar, I can see that all dependencies are specifically included, except the JavaFX classes.

What I've tried:

- Build the jar with `javapackager`
- Tinker around with the javafx-maven-plugin
- Explicitly add JavaFX as dependency in my pom.xml in the hopes that the assembly-plugin would package it for me

None of the above was successful. The only way I'm able to launch my app is directly out of the IDE, which seems to mean that the JavaFX libs *are* still available on my system.

Any ideas on how to get this to run (again)?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using oracle jdk when build the project?

Comment: @mrmcwolf It's configured to use /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64, so pretty sure, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

I ran my jar with openJDK 11 which does not include JavaFX while building it with openJDK 8. Case closed.

**Findings, details and reasons**

Since my IDE was able to run my code without issues, I presumed the problem to be specific to my config/machine. As it turns out Canonical/Ubuntu decided

> [For] Bionic [...] **move the default JRE/JDK** in main to OpenJDK 11 in
>   September/October 2018 as an SRU. [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037655/58591)

And, as pointed out on a different SO Thread:

> JavaFX 11 is not part of the JDK **anymore** [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470141/617458)

(This also includes instructions how to fix this with JDK 11)

And finally, as Murphy's law had it, I set up my packaging the project on October 4th, and decided to install eclipse via apt on October 8th which includes `openjdk-11-jdk:amd64` (this is logged in the useful `/var/log/apt/history.log`).

This *also* updated my `/etc/alternatives/java` to point to v11. Since I ran my jar without explicitly specifying the java binary, it broke.

Running

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar target/app.jar
```

for a quick test works as expected. Now I only need to upgrade my project to openJDK 11 or else always run my app with the specific JDK 8.

Comment: For what it's worth, your "short answer" is worded "I ran my jar with openJDK 11 while which does not include JavaFX while building it with openJDK 8." Is this exactly what you meant to say? Ideally I'd have loved to be able to figure it out from the rest of the answer but I'm afraid I can't.

Comment: @pateksan that´s exactly what I meant. I ran `java -jar [...]`. That meant Java 8  before I received my Ubuntu updates, and Java 11 afterwards. To fix it, maybe see basically the same question on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139155/recent-upgrade-of-openjfx-broke-my-installed-application/1139156#1139156

Comment: Not sure why I only noticed your response now. Thanks but I was on about "while which does not include". It could be that the word "while" is used in this bit accidentally (perhaps you reworded the sentence at some point). If I had a better understanding of the wider subject I might be able to interpret your sentence correctly. But at my level of knowledge it just seems like you may have meant various things. Does that make sense?

Comment: @pateksan You are absolutely right. I fixed the sentence. Ty