# How to run ControlsFX sample application using Java 11 and JavaFX 11

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

[ControlsFX website](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) says:

> If you want to play with the ControlsFX sample application, simply
>   download the ControlsFX release and run the following command on the
>   command prompt (be sure to replace the * with the actual version
>   number of FXSampler and ControlsFX-samples):
>
> `java -jar controlsfx-samples-*.jar`

I've downloaded [ControlsFX 9.0.0](http://fxexperience.com/downloads/controlsfx-9-0-0/) which is said to be for users of Java 9 and later.

When I run `java -jar controlsfx-samples-9.0.0.jar` I get

> Error: Could not find or load main class fxsampler.FXSampler
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

But that's OK, as according to [Run HelloWorld using JavaFX 11 guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx), I have to add modules.

So I try `java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls -jar controlsfx-samples-9.0.0.jar` and I get

> Missing JavaFX application class fxsampler.FXSampler

I execute all commands from `controlsfx-9.0.0` directory which contains `controlsfx-9.0.0.jar`, `controlsfx-samples-9.0.0.jar` and `fxsampler-1.0.10.jar`.

Output of `java -version` for me is:

> openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
After following [Slaw's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872562/how-to-run-controlsfx-sample-application-using-java-11-and-javafx-11#comment92662203_52872562) and running `java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web -jar controlsfx-samples-9.0.0.jar` I get

```
Initialising FXSampler sample scanner...
        Discovering projects...
                Found project 'ControlsFX', with sample base package 'org.controlsfx.samples'
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class impl.org.controlsfx.version.VersionChecker
        at org.controlsfx.control.ControlsFXControl.(ControlsFXControl.java:35)
        at org.controlsfx.control.WorldMapView.(WorldMapView.java:93)
        at org.controlsfx.samples.HelloWorldMapView.(HelloWorldMapView.java:55)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
        at fxsampler.util.SampleScanner.discoverSamples(SampleScanner.java:86)
        at fxsampler.FXSampler.start(FXSampler.java:106)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application fxsampler.FXSampler
```

Comment: Similar issue as this other SO thread ? [JavaFX packaging: NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761836/javafx-packaging-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: @keybored Well, it had been similar before I've added `--add-modules`. And the thread says that the problem was in absence of JavaFX in JDK 11, but https://openjfx.io/ states that ControlsFX supports JavaFX 11, so I guess I have another problem.

Comment: You've added `javafx.controls` which will also pull in `javafx.graphics` and `javafx.base`, but do the samples need any of the other modules? Such as `javafx.fxml` or `javafx.web`?

Comment: @Slaw You we right. Now I get another exception. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in [PR #720](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull-requests/720/modularization-of-controlsfx-and-java-11/diff). So new Maven artifacts will incorporate the fix.

Full issue history can be seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/885/controlsfx-on-javafx-11).

Comment: How does a new Maven artifact help with running it from the command line?

Comment: @dmolony All the jars you download from ControlsFX website are maven artifacts just packed in a zip archive. You can check yourself by downloading [current archive](http://fxexperience.com/downloads/controlsfx-9-0-0/) and comparing the jars in it with [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.controlsfx).

Comment: It still doesn't work. I just downloaded the 9.0.0 jars, and gave the command as per the instructions. Error: Could not find or load main class fxsampler.FXSampler

Comment: Then I tried it with the instructions above. Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Comment: @dmolony 9.0.0 jars are NOT compatible with JavaFX 11. You have to wait for the new ones.
As stated on https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx: "For users of Java 11 and later, download will be coming soon!"

Comment: As the OP's question was about Java 11, and because the accepted answer (this one) says 'Fixed in PR #720', it seemed safe to assume that it was fixed for Java 11.

Comment: @dmolony developers of ControlsFX have made a fix, so that ControlsFX can run on JDK 11, but they haven't built artifacts with that fix included. If you want, you can build ControlsFX on your own.