# JAVA 11 and JavaFX in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I created JavaFX project in IntelliJ IDEA 2018. I have installed Java JDK 11 and my project (Maven) includes all needed dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when I try to launch app, I am getting:

```
    Error:(3, 26) java: cannot access javafx.application.Application
  bad class file: C:\Users\Baterka\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11\javafx-graphics-11-win.jar(javafx/application/Application.class)
    class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Where is problem? What are versions 54 and 52? Is JavaFX supported in new Java 11?

Comment: Make sure your project settings are also pointing to JDK 11

Comment: @JoséPereda I checked. They  point

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to execute your program with Java8 (class file version 52) whereas your JavaFX is compiled for Java10 (class file version 54) which does not work because Java8 does not know this version.

Comment: Every place where I can change it its set to Java 11

Comment: Are you using the latest version of maven and all plugins? Do you use Java 11 to execute maven?

Comment: @mipa yes i do...

Comment: I added plugins: `org.apache.maven.plugins`, `org.codehaus.mojo` and properity: `<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>`... Now I am getting error: `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470141/3956070)

Comment: @JoséPereda not working for me :(

Answer (score 3):

try adding this to your pom.xml file.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11.0.1</source>
                <target>11.0.1</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It would be better if you update all your maven plugins also. see this [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_tdK8zWr_w), that's where I got the configuration.

Answer (score -2):

Just try to use JAVA 10, you just have to create new folder with that version, and you dont need to include any library. After that try to run it. and here's the link if you want to download it

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-javase10-downloads.html