# Using JavaFX with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-11

I've followed a tutorial precisely and I can't seem to get it to work. The tutorial is under `JavaFX and Intellij` `Non-modular from IDE` sections: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-java

Here is the error message I receive when trying to run the default Intellij Idea JavaFX project:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=53491:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\jonat\IdeaProjects\Tawe-Lib FX\out\production\Tawe-Lib FX;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\src.zip;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar" sample.Main
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This makes little sense to me as I can see `javafx.base` under `lib` on the sidebar:
[image]

The path leading to `jdk-11.0.1` and `javafx-sdk-11.0.1`:

> C:\Program Files\Java

Java is installed:

```
C:\Users\jonat>java --version
openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

`JAVA_HOME` variable (mentioned in guide) is set:

```
C:\Users\jonat>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1
```

`PATH_TO_FX` variable is set:

```
C:\Users\jonat>echo %PATH_TO_FX%
C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib
```

I have really no idea where to go from here. I have followed the tutorial precisely, and it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you require more info please just drop a comment about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij can't recognize javafx 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11)

Comment: What does your `%PATH_TO_FX%` print? Can you run the project from command line? Note also the docs include a tutorial for [IntelliJ](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij), did you check it?

Comment: @JoséPereda Added what `%PATH_TO_FX%` is set to at end of question.

Comment: @JoséPereda I can run the HelloFX example they give in the tutorial however I do not know how I would run this project from command line, and yes I did follow the tutorial for Intellij in the docs.

Comment: The tutorial precisely gives you all the commands you have to use on command line, just open a terminal at your project's root and run them?

Comment: @JoséPereda It gives the commands to run a single file, under the `Run HelloWorld using JavaFX 11` section which I can do. It does not give commands to run an Intellij project. It says `Click Run -> Run... to run the project, now it should work fine.`.

Comment: You have posted you were following the [modular](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular) tutorial, which gives the command line instructions. Anyway, when you run from IntelliJ, you can see the actual command that is executed, so you can copy that and paste it on a terminal, and see what goes wrong.

Comment: @JoséPereda I must apologise, I do not know how I messed that up, I've changed the link to what it should be, I was following the non-modular tutorial.

Comment: I don't really know the difference between modular and non-modular so I just went with what would appear to the the simplest and first presented to me.

Comment: I followed this tutorial and it seems to be easier to follow https://www.cs.rit.edu/~csci142/Resources/setup.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Based on the posted command line, this is what IntelliJ applies to run your project:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

So in the VM options you have set *verbatim* what the [tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij) says:

[image]

But you haven't applied *your real path* for `PATH_TO_FX`, as it is suggested in the picture inserted after that command in the tutorial:

[image]

IntelliJ doesn't resolve that variable and the module path is not set, hence you get the expected error that reveals that the JavaFX modules are not found:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

**Solution**

This can be solved in two ways:

1. Apply your path:

Edit run configurations, and in the VM options add your path:

```
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Apply, and run. It should work.

2. Add the environment variable

You can also set an environment variable. Go to `IntelliJ->File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->Path Variables`, and add `PATH_TO_FX`, with the path to the `lib` folder:

[image]

And then you can use the literals `$PATH_TO_FX$` (Does not work for IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (Community Edition) on Windows) or `${PATH_TO_FX}` in the VM options:

```
--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Apply, and run.

Note that this is a more permanent solution that can be apply to any other JavaFX project.

Comment: Thank you so much! In my case Intellij had somehow stored an incorrect `PATH_TO_FX` in `IntelliJ->File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->Path Variables`, which was overriding my system environment variable. Removing the incorrect path fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The top solution might be working with a simple case, where you did not specify **VM options**, but sometimes it might be more complicated.

If the top solution is not your case then there is another thing to check: check whether your **project root folder** contains **.iml** file of your **Module** name (*check in project structure*).

If the **.iml** is missing then you need to recreate the Module in **project structure**. 
You need to recreate the module in project structure, so module will generate and link .iml file.