# Java Error : Module javafx.base not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

so I started to make a javafx project in intelliJ, but it prompted me with this error :

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found

[here's screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkwmO.png)

any solution?

Comment: Please, edit your answer - add code and stacktrace instead of screenshot

Comment: If you haven't already read the _JavaFX and IntelliJ_ section of [Getting Started with JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs).

Comment: Duplicated of [Using JavaFX with Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435349/using-javafx-with-intellij-idea/53436569#53436569)

Answer (score -1):

You should add javafx dependency with maven or you can use javax.swing library.

Comment: What does swing have to do with this?