# "Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw" for JavaFX on IntelliJ IDEA Windows

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, javafx, direct3d

While trying to run a simple JavaFX program on IntelliJ IDEA, I kept getting a long line of errors in the console that started with "Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw".

I'm certain I correctly used the openjfx libraries.

I've tried using Java Versions 11.0.4 and 12.0.1 for the project as well as JavaFX 11.0.3 and JavaFX 12.0.1. I had no idea if this would make a difference, but it still results in the same errors.

I looked up some information about "d3d," and according to a Steam Support page: "D3D errors typically occur if you are running the game at settings which your machine does not adequately support or if you are running outdated video drivers."

Is there a way to fix this, or is my hardware simply out of date?

```js
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
 ... 5 more
```

Comment: Have you followed the documentation https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij ?

Comment: @JoséPereda I followed it again, and the libraries were fine. I added the lines to the VM options, which I hadn't done before. This got rid of most of the errors, but left me with this: "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found
"

Comment: We can't help if you don't post what you have done. But there are already very similar questions, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11).

Comment: @JoséPereda O.K. Thank You