# JavaFX not found by IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

On my previous laptop, I could easily create a `JavaFX` app from `IntelliJ`'s JavaFX template. Although I have a new better computer, If I repeated the process, IntelliJ would tell me the JDK does not have JavaFX.

Keep in mind that I'm a starter, so I would appreciate it if you could give me answers that do not involve  `maven` or `gradle`.

I've tried Oracle JDK 11, Zulu OpenJDK 8 and OpenJFX 11.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11) solves part of my problem, however, the problem is that I cannot add the JavaFX JDK as JDK. If I try to add the lib folder as a library it says some components are missing.

Comment: See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11)

Comment: @JoséPereda I watched the tutorial and whatever I did I could not add the jdk, IntelliJ said `selected directory is not a valid home for a jdk`. And my problem is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-1, althought it solves a part of it, in my case I cannot even add the jdk, wich is the first problem I'm facing.

Comment: @Skwead Can you create a simple command-line Java application. It is a good idea to share the location which you are pointing to(maybe screenshots). From Java 11, JavaFX is not part of JDK and you must add its libs to your application.

Comment: I made the HelloWorld classic and it worked perfectly. I put my JavaFX jdk 11 at `C:\Program Files\JavaFX-SDK\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2`, and my Java11 jdk is at `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.4.11-hotspot`. As I said, if I add libraries there are still missing components, even on the plain JavaFx template.

Comment: @Skwead I am pretty sure that you did not follow instructions properly. Check this video, It might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82QcFSstJs0

Comment: Many thanks @ElyasHadizadeh, that video helped a lot, but I had to watch the next one too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtOgoomDewo, where it is taught how to setup the project. Many thanks to everyone that helped me.