# Can't load fxml file by FXMLLoader (InvocationTargetException)

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I first time try to use JavaFx with Maven. By this topic: link [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11), I configured project. But whatever I do I can't load fxml file, because "getClass().getResource(path)" return null.

I changed path, start it with '/' and without, changed packages, created packages, deleted packages, changed references in module-info, but this is not work.

struct: https://ibb.co/Hhwzk8b

```
module LogAggregator {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;

    opens fxml to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.github.PavelKisliuk;
}
```

//----------------------------------------------------

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

              String path = "fxml/Input.fxml";
              FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
      fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(path));
      Parent fxmlMainWindow = fxmlLoader.load();

      //start-up window
      //-----------------------------------------------
      Scene s = new Scene(fxmlMainWindow);
      primaryStage.setScene(s);
      primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
      launch(args);
  }
}
```

May be somebody know this problem and can help me. Without maven I don't have any problem's.

**DECISION**

Such path:

```
String path = "/fxml/Input.fxml";
```

Plus two string's to module-info:

```
opens com.github.PavelKisliuk.controller to javafx.fxml;
exports com.github.PavelKisliuk.controller to javafx.fxml;
```

Comment: You're currently using a relative path, which is being resolved against `Main`. You need to use an absolute path here: `"/fxml/Input.fxml"`. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) of `getResource` for more information.

Comment: Check, if the directory IntellIJ uses as classpath to run the program include a subdirectory `fxml` that contains the `Input.fxml` file and use the path `"/fxml/Input.fxml"`...

Answer (score 0):

Your Main class seems to be in the package `com.gihub.PavelKisliuk`, but resources are under `fxml`. In this situation relative path you use resolves to non-existent `com.gihub.PavelKisliuk/fxml/Input.fxml`.

Solutions:

1. Preferrable: move resources into 'com.gihub.PavelKisliuk'
2. Move Main class out of 'com.gihub.PavelKisliuk'

Hope this helps...