# Gradle how to add VM option to run and deploy jfoenix on javafx 11 idea?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-11, javafx-11

I'm using javafx 11.0.2 and java 11.0.3 
In order to discover 'gradle' I downloaded this project https://github.com/fthdgn/java11-javafx-demo and when I add jfoenix controls in main.fxml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.fthdgn.app.controller.MainController">
    <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10"
          AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10" fx:id="vbox">
        <TextField fx:id="inputTextField"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#reveseButtonClicked" text="Reverse"/>
        <TextField fx:id="outputTextField"/>
        <JFXTextField fx:id="tf"/>
        <JFXButton text="AZUL" fx:id="button"/>
        <JFXTabPane>
            <Tab>
            </Tab>
        </JFXTabPane>

    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

I got this famous error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTabPaneSkin (in module com.jfoenix) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TabPaneBehavior (in module javafx.controls) because module javafx.controls does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior to module com.jfoenix
```

I have edited the build.gradle to add some jvm options( for module app ) like this

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.zyxist.chainsaw' version '0.3.1'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.15.1'
}
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

import org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

group 'com.fthdgn'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = mainClass

def currentOS = OperatingSystem.current()
def platform
if (currentOS.isWindows()) {
    platform = 'win'
} else if (currentOS.isLinux()) {
    platform = 'linux'
} else if (currentOS.isMacOsX()) {
    platform = 'mac'
}

jlink {
    javaHome.set(Jvm.current().getJavaHome().getAbsolutePath())

}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:${platform}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:${platform}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11:${platform}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11:${platform}"
    compile group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '9.0.9'


}

run {
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix']
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix']
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix']
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix']
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix']

}
```

I just added

```
run {
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix']
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix']
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix']
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix']
    jvmArgs += ['--add-exports', 'javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix']

}
```

And run like a charm but this is do anything for deploying , how do I do to set this jvmArgs for all task to use jfoenix in gradle with javafx 11 and java 11 ?

```
module com.fthdgn.app {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive com.jfoenix;
    opens com.fthdgn.app to javafx.graphics;
    opens com.fthdgn.app.controller to javafx.fxml;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using the `module-info.java` file in the project for the proper modules support without the JVM options hacks? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897944/104891

Comment: This is my module-info.java
module com.fthdgn.app {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive com.jfoenix;
    opens com.fthdgn.app to javafx.graphics;
    opens com.fthdgn.app.controller to javafx.fxml;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij) for JavaFX 11+, section Modular with Gradle.

There is a [sample](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Modular/Gradle/hellofx) that makes use of the JavaFX gradle plugin, to deal with the JavaFX dependencies and the build and run tasks, and the [Jlink](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin) plugin, to deal with deployment of a custom image runtime.

All you have to do is add the Jfoenix dependency to that project, modify its source code accordingly, and finally include the required `jvmArgs` in both `run` and `jlink` tasks, like this:

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.15.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '9.0.9'
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

run {
    jvmArgs = [
            "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
    ]
}

jlink {
    launcher {
        name = 'hellofx'
        jvmArgs = [
                "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
                "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix",
                "--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix",
                "--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix",
                "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
        ]
    }
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/org.openjfx.MainApp"
```

Now you can run your project with:

```
./gradlew run
```

and create the runtime image with:

```
./gradlew jlink
```

Once it has finished building, you can run it from the script:

```
build/image/bin/hellofx
```

Answer (score 0):

this didn't work for me in JDK 16:

```
run {
    jvmArgs = [
            "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
    ]
}
```

what worked instead is

```
run {
    jvmArgs = [
            "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix",
            "--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix",
    ]
}
```

the same thing with Jlink VM args