# Javafx - SDK 13

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, sdk

I'm still new to java, and this is my very first JavaFX project, I have Intellij and I have installed the latest java SDK from the official website, which is version 13 the fxml file scene builder has no problem but the problem is with the text side, as it shows a message telling that the SDK is not configured and that the packages are not yet installed...

I tried doing the same project on another slower machine with SDK 11 installed and everything looks alright, so I'm pretty sure it's all about the SDK 13.

Is there anything that I have to install/configure to get JavaFX run?

Comment: JavaFX is not part of JDK, it must be downloaded and installed: [What's New](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#NewFeature)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I did install the JavaFX two folders from the same website, tried to point the IDE to these folders but nothing happens as there are no libraries or packages installed inside the folders.
I'm doing something wrong, right? :D

Comment: Did you *really* install JavaFX though? You downloaded something and you put it somewhere, but that's not all there is to it. Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11) question? Did you look at the IntelliJ [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html)?

Comment: `it shows a message telling that the SDK is not configured and that the packages are not yet installed...` show us the screenshot. Make sure the [Project JDK is set](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#change-project-sdk) for the 13 JDK you downloaded on system.

Comment: Did you follow the official documentation? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is not a part of Java anymore, You have to download it as an external resource and have to add it to the global library.
https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
you can find the latest versions of JavaFX here.