# Zulu with Java 11 and JavaFX Docker Image

Tags: java, maven, docker, javafx, azul-zulu

I am trying to setup a Docker Image based on Zulu OpenJDK 8 width JavaFX and Maven. But unfortunately JavaFX is not part in the debian binary.

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-debian:8u222

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.2
ARG SHA=d941423d115cd021514bfd06c453658b1b3e39e6240969caf4315ab7119a77299713f14b620fb2571a264f8dff2473d8af3cb47b05acf0036fc2553199a5c1ee
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && rm -f /usr/bin/mvn \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to build JavaFX based applications:

```
[ERROR] /builds/myproject/java-clients/examples/javafx/src/main/java/com/myproject/demo/fx/DemoFxClient.java:[28,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
```

I've also tried to just use the openjdk docker image:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim-buster

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.2
ARG SHA=d941423d115cd021514bfd06c453658b1b3e39e6240969caf4315ab7119a77299713f14b620fb2571a264f8dff2473d8af3cb47b05acf0036fc2553199a5c1ee
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        openjfx \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && rm -f /usr/bin/mvn \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

Was anyone able to create a Docker Image supporting JavaFX builds?

Answer (score 3):

I have found out that the original problem was not with the JavaFX setup, but that JavaFX dependencies need to be added as maven dependencies.

**Zulu JDK 11 with Java FX and Maven Docker Image** (e.g. to be used in GitLab Pipeline)

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.2
ARG SHA=d941423d115cd021514bfd06c453658b1b3e39e6240969caf4315ab7119a77299713f14b620fb2571a264f8dff2473d8af3cb47b05acf0036fc2553199a5c1ee
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

# Install libraries used for builds
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        software-properties-common \
        wget \
        gnupg \
        curl \
        ca-certificates \
        bzip2 \
        zip \
        unzip \
        git \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Zulu 11
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0xB1998361219BD9C9 \
    && apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.azulsystems.com/debian stable main' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends zulu-11

# Install Maven
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && rm -f /usr/bin/mvn \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

# Add JavaFX
RUN curl -fsSL -o /tmp/javafx-11-0-2-sdk-linux.zip http://gluonhq.com/download/javafx-11-0-2-sdk-linux/ \
  && cd /tmp/ \
  && unzip /tmp/javafx-11-0-2-sdk-linux.zip \
  && cp -arf /tmp/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/* /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64/lib/
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
  <!--- ... --->
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>11</javafx.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.openjfx.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

These StackOverflow questions / CodeRepos have been helpful:

- [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11)
- https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Non-Modular/