# How to build Javafx + Spring for production using maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, javafx, package

I have created **Javafx (13)** application with **spring boot (2.2.4) and jpa** integration using **maven build tool**. Now my sample application is working fine. but I don't have clear idea about how this application move to production environment. My questions are

1. How can I package application
2. Can I create setup file using application jar file
3. How I install application in different desktop environment (Windows, Linux)

Following are the technologies and tool which used

- Javafx 13
- Spring boot 2.2.4
- maven 3.6.1
- Intelij Idea
- Ubuntu 18.04

**pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.emp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-javafx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-javafx</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.emp.springbootjavafx.SpringBootJavafxApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.emp.springbootjavafx.SpringBootJavafxApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.emp.springbootjavafx.SpringBootJavafxApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <!-- copy fxml and css resources -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Module-info.java class**

```
module spring.boot.javafx {

    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.boot.starter.jdbc;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.xml.bind;
    requires net.bytebuddy;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires com.fasterxml.classmate;

    exports com.emp.springbootjavafx.controllers;
    opens com.emp.springbootjavafx;

}
```

**application.properties file**

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none

#=========================================================================
#DATA SOURCE PROPERTIES
#=========================================================================
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test_db_fx
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

#=========================================================================
#JPA PROPERTIES
#=========================================================================
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**main class**

```
package com.emp.springbootjavafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootJavafxApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent rootNode;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(SpringBootJavafxApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
        rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJavafxApplication.class);
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }
}
```

After build project with the above configuration I tryied to run jar file using ***java -jar app.jar command***. but i got below error message

[image]

Comment: post the error as text instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

1: Consult this: [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11)

2 + 3: The Jar file should be able to be launched on any computer with Java installed, but if you wanted to wrap it in a .exe, id use a tool like Inno Setup and/or Launch4j. You can use those via Maven.