# Why Eclipse does not recognize JavaFX, Even after adding JavaFx user libararies?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

[All Added Libraries in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PwKp.png)

I am using everything with latest version. Still all those red warnings dont go away. You should check image up. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11) - make sure the fx modules are added to the module-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All videos and tutorials recommanded adding JavaFX as user libraries to Classpath. This does not work at all. **Adding JavaFX User library under Modulepath only worked.** I done everything correctly but adding user libraries under class did not solve the problem. My problem is now solved. Please feel free to comment or suggest if anything I did wrong.

[Image of added libaries and problem solved no red errors showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JpJq.png)

Comment: _All videos and tutorials recommanded adding JavaFX as user libraries to Classpath_ a bold statement ;) The duplicate I referenced certainly doesn't - it clearly states to add them to the module-path.

Comment: @kleopatra My apologies, I seen the content some of it was unclear and less understandable. I miss took some answers for Intellj instead of Eclipse. Thank you for the referrals given by you. Yes, I respect your help and I went through the given links. Sorry for miss understanding the stuff.