# JavaFX lib can not be build any more since JavaFX 17

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-17

I have a JavaFX lib which I use for my projects. When I set the maven dependencies to JavaFX 16 the lib can be build via "clean install" without any errors.

When I switch the maven dependency to 17 I get several error like:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] C:\kisters\workspaces\2021-09-workspace\water-widgets.ui.javafx.lib\src\main\java\de\kisters\ui\water\widgets\propertysheet\editor\PSButton.java:[4,27] error: package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] C:\kisters\workspaces\2021-09-workspace\water-widgets.ui.javafx.lib\src\main\java\de\kisters\ui\water\widgets\propertysheet\editor\PSButton.java:[5,26] error: package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] C:\kisters\workspaces\2021-09-workspace\water-widgets.ui.javafx.lib\src\main\java\de\kisters\ui\water\widgets\propertysheet\editor\PSButton.java:[6,26] error: package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] C:\kisters\workspaces\2021-09-workspace\water-widgets.ui.javafx.lib\src\main\java\de\kisters\ui\water\widgets\propertysheet\APropertySheetEditor.java:[5,28] error: package javafx.beans.property does not exist
```

I searched the net an found this issue [openjdk](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8264998).

It seems that during the compile process empty modules are used. Does anyone know how to solve this for my maven build?

Comment: Update by Johan Vos: https://twitter.com/johanvos/status/1436265556244566016

Comment: on openjfx-dev: https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2021-September/031934.html

Comment: Added replication steps and suggested workaround (use JavaFX 16 until this issue is fixed in JavaFX 17) as an answer to the related question: [IntelliJ doesn't load javafx packages from Maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137635/1155209).