# Maven does not compile appliction with JavaFX 17

Tags: java, maven, javafx

This demo program illustrates a problem I have found when
using Maven to compile the application using Java JDK 17
and JavaFX 17. I'm using Maven 3.8.1.

If I compile the application in a terminal
with Maven, then these errors (excerpt) are produced:

```
% mvn clean compile
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ hellomvn ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/due1/workspace-tmp/btx.prog.one.hellomvn/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /path_to/btx.prog.one.hellomvn/src/main/java/btx/prog/one/hellomvn/App.java:[6,26] package javafx.application does not exist
[ERROR] /path_to/btx.prog.one.hellomvn/src/main/java/btx/prog/one/hellomvn/App.java:[7,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
...
```

However, if imported
into Eclipse 2021-09 (with Java 17 Support Feature) or
IntelliJ, then the application compiles and can be
executed.

If I change the JavaFX version in the POM from `17` to `16`,
then Maven compiles the application:

```
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <javafx.version>16</javafx.version>
```

Using `mvn -U clean compile` does not help either. I noticed
when using Maven's (big-) `-X` option that with JavaFX 17, the
JAR's of JavaFX are *not* on the classpath, but on the
module-path only, whereas when specifying JavaFX 16,
the JAR's of JavaFX 16 *are* on both, the classpath
and module-path.

Any clue?

The complete program can be found here:

https://gitlab.com/edubuis/btx.prog.one.hellomvn

Comment: 17 is broken in Maven, try [17.0.0.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml/17.0.0.1).

Comment: I think this is related to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116905/intellij-doesnt-load-javafx-packages-from-maven-dependencies.
jewelsea answered it ("use JavaFX 16 until further notice"). Thanks.

Comment: I updated the recommendation in the linked duplicate from recommending to downgrade to version 16, to, instead, use version 17.0.0.1, as that now fixes the maven packaging issue which caused this error for the initial release of version 17 of the JavaFX 17 maven modules.

Comment: Thank you, jewelsea, for this solution. It works!