# Getting empty jars while importing javafx libraries with maven or gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, javafx, openjfx

I wrote

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: '17.0.1'
```

in my geadle file and got empty jar. On [jars page](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.1/) I see, that [generic jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.1/javafx-base-17.0.1.jar) is really empty, while platform specific are not.

How should I describe my dependency here then?

---

Next I wrote

```
plugins {
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}

javafx {
    version = "17"
    modules = [ 'javafx.base' ]
}
```

but this didn't help

Comment: The javafx 17 modules in maven central (used by gradle) are broken, try using [javafx 17.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137635/1155209).

Comment: All of the implementation is packed into the platform specific jars which will (if everything works correctly) also be downloaded and used for your environment without you having to specify anything else (at least maven works that way, I don't use gradle, but I believe it will be the same).  The non-platform specific jars are very small because they contain no implementation, it is just how the JavaFX team chose to package the maven artifacts.

Comment: @jewelsea is doesn't download. Why would it?

Comment: I don't know how the mechanism works, I just know that it works, at least if you use Maven, and I am sure Gradle is not different in that respect.  You can see the [javafx-base artifacts here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.1/), javafx-base-17.0.1.jar is only 302 bytes.  javafx-base-17.0.1-win.jar is 746018 bytes.  Without the platform specific jars you don't have an implementation.

Comment: I checked it out to see how it works, it's pretty simple, the platform specific artifact is a dependency of the the non-platform specific artifact.  See the [pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.1/javafx-base-17.0.1.pom).  Fetching transitive dependencies is something both maven and gradle will do by default.

Comment: Hm, it really worked. May be 17-th was really broken...

Comment: Yes, it really is . . .