# InvalidModuleDescriptorException - JavaFX

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, javafx

I was just creating a JavaFX project with Template Generator in Intellij Idea with Kotlin, When I try to run the Build the application with gradle I faced `InvalidModuleDescriptorException`.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: D:\Project Templates\BaseApp\build\classes\java\main
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package org.example.baseapp not found in module
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.22'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.10.0'
}


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'baseApp'
    mainClass = 'org.example.baseapp.HelloApplication'
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}

javafx {
    version = '21'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

And this is My `module-info.java`:

```
module baseApp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires kotlin.stdlib;


    opens org.example.baseapp to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.example.baseapp.gui;
}
```

This is how my project structure looks:

[image: Project Structure]

Also I try to delete `module-info.java`  and run application according to [this Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56724298/22324209)

But it throws other warning:

`WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @2767866b'`

How can I resolve this issue? Any help would be helpful!

Edit:  I have created a new Project in JavaFx with Kotlin and Gradle.
This is my project structure doesn't changed anything, this was right from the Intellij JavaFX plugin Generator. I don't know why it throws this error. It happens only in Gradle Build, not happened in Maven build. I even tried with Java with Gradle, still same issue retains.
[image: Here is my project structure]

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

**Update: I used MAVEN and not GRADLE when creating the project which is why this worked for me, with GRADLE is broken as noted in the comments and the question.**

When I wrote this answer, I forgot that this issue had already been raised when Idea+JavaFX+Gradle+Kotlin was used with Idea's new JavaFX project wizard.

See the duplicate for more information:

- [IntelliJ New JavaFX Project dosent work - InvalidModuleDescriptorException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69815500/intellij-new-javafx-project-dosent-work-invalidmoduledescriptorexception)

As noted in comments and duplicate with Idea 2023.3.3 it will generate broken projects for Idea+JavaFX+Gradle+Kotlin that do not run in the IDE by clicking the green arrow.  Those projects will still run if you use Gradle to run them (in the IDE go to the Gradle pane and double-click on the Tasks | application | run).

#### Original answer

Instructions on how to create a new JavaFX project using Kotlin are provided by IntelliJ:

- [Create a new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).

When I followed these instructions in Idea 2023.3.3, it just worked.

Your project differs from the generated project. You probably changed the project after it was generated and broke it.

You don't have any code in `org.example.baseapp`. Even though you have code in `org.example.baseapp.gui`, that is a different package.  There is no java package with the name `org.example.baseapp`.  You can't `opens org.example.baseapp to javafx.fxml` because the package you are trying to open does not exist.

Your JavaFX application and controller are in `org.example.baseapp.gui`, so to make them accessible to JavaFX, define your `module-info.java` based on this:

```
module org.example.baseapp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires kotlin.stdlib;

    opens org.example.baseapp.gui to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.example.baseapp.gui;
}
```

The fxml needs to be accessible.  The new JavaFX project wizard for Kotlin generates this line in the application:

```
val fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader(HelloApplication::class.java.getResource("hello-view.fxml"))
```

For that to work, then `hello-view.fxml` needs to be in
a resource folder corresponding to the HelloApplication class:

```
resources\org\example\baseapp\gui\hello-view.fxml
```

You don't need a `java` folder for the `module-info.java`, you can just place it directly under the `kotlin` folder.  This is what the default project generated by the New JavaFX Project wizard for Kotlin does.

Your build script is wrong, it has:

```
application {
    mainModule = 'baseApp'
    mainClass = 'org.example.baseapp.HelloApplication'
}
```

But your class is named `org.example.baseapp.gui.HelloApplication`.

There is not much in your project, I suggest you just scrap it, create a new one that works using the wizard, then slowly make modifications to get it to work how you want, testing at each step.

Comment: I created a two project from scratch using Intellij Project wizard, with kotlin/Gradle  and Java/Gradle, still facing the issue. Also created a project with kotlin/maven, it has no issue. I Have updated my question could you help me out?

Comment: Yes. I had chosen Maven when generating the project rather than Gradle, which is why it worked for me. See the update and the duplicate for more info.