# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application on one of two projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have two projects that I work with using two different computers. To be more precise, one project is just an updated version of the first one. So basically the first project is a desktop application with Hibernate and JavaFX and the second one is the same as the first one, but it also has Spring in it. Now the problem I face is that the second application doesn't even start (the desktop application part), because there is an error: "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application", while the first one starts without any problems.

Some more things about both projects:

- Second project is published in GitHub respository, to make it easier to transfer files from one computer to another
- The spring part in second project works without problems (Tomcat starts, that is okay)
- In both projects SDK is the same

Also, I have set up the module-info file, which has all the required things:

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires mysql.connector.java;
requires java.persistence;
requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
requires java.sql;
requires spring.context;
requires spring.web;
requires spring.core;
requires com.google.gson;
```

pom.xml file is also set.
I tried searching for the solution, but most of them suggest to try adding VM option to configuration, but that gives me another error: javafx.controls not found.
Is there anything else I could try?
It really bugs me that the second project is just an expansion of the first one, but while the first one works perfectly, second one fails.
Is it something about Git?
Also, I will try to launch the second application on the primary computer (the one that the application was initially being updated on) tomorrow to see if it works there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11)

Comment: How are you starting up each application?