# How to make new application class in JavaFX using intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I deleted default application and controller and made new ones to rename them. But I got error

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code is very simple.

```
package com.example.demo5;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I set up javafx library and vmoptions, and checked that it ran with default application and controller.

Must I use the default files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Idea new [JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) to generate your project, Application and Controller classes and sample FXML.

If you want to rename the generated code, don't delete and recreate the generated Application, Controller, and sample FXML, [rename them](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html) through a refactoring.

When you do this, the IDE will automatically reconfigure everything in the project to use the new names.